# Model doesn't learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, supervised-learning

I am newbie to Machine Learning. For some reason, my CNN doesn't learn at all. I tried on different datasets, but result is the same: loss and accuracy are changing just a little (most likely this is just an inaccuracy). Maybe I configured something incorrectly or did not do something at lot.

The task is to create a lip movement generator based on face photos and audio recordings (supervised learning)

[audio.mp3 + face.jpg] -> [1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 5.jpg, 6.jpg ... ]

1. I do normalize input data,
2. I set loss function = `mean_squared_error`
3. I set metrics = `[accuracy, mean_squared_error]`
4. I set optimizer = `Adam`,
5. The dataset is large enough to see at least some results = 2000 videos
6. The `epoch` number = 2,
7. `batch_size` = 16
8. Learning_rate = 0.001 (default)

The model structure diagram is below. I chose the number of layers and their types at random.

Input `frame` = face, picture 50x60, channels = 3. Shape = (50, 60, 3)

Input `mfcc` = numerical coefficients. Shape = (20, 43)

Output: 24 images 50x60

I'm trying to generate output = lips movement (video = many frames) by audio (mfcc) and face image.

Here you are my logs and model structure

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using MSE loss with accuracy metrics? That makes no sense.

Comment: Okay, I agree, accuracy metrics is odd. Let’s look only at MSE loss

Comment: Sure, but is your task regression or classification?

Comment: Yep, it is regression